# If codeigniter model returns 0 rows, display custom error message. How to extend to a general case?

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, models

I have a variety of functions within my models which serve a different purpose.

One for example looks up the data for a given $_GET variable in the URL string.

I am trying to work out a way of displaying an error message if there is no matching row in the database due to url string manipulation for example.

My first idea was simply to return an error message (if there is an error) with each call to the function, then simply have an if statement whereby if there is an error, an error view is shown, and if not the normal view is shown..

Problem with this is that this function is called numerous times in my controller, and other similar functions are called throughout my code which need similar error handling..

I dont want millions of similar if/else statements all over my code to handle errors..

Anyone got any better ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) item of the session class. You can concatenate error messages and put them in the flashdata item to display.

```
my_function(){
    // code that determines if there is an error returns => $error
    if ($error)
    {
        // concat previous and current errors
        $new_error = $this->session->flashdata('errors') . $error;
        // replace 'errors' with newly concatenated errors
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $new_error);
    }
}
```

This will keep track of all errors generated through each request and allow you to display a "list" of errors for that particular request.

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');
```